# How to check if a particular version of flash player is installed or not in C#.?

Tags: c#, flash, registry

I want to check from my code if a particular version of flash player is installed or not.
I used the following code

```
using Microsoft.Win32

RegistryKey RK = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\SOFTWARE\\Macromedia\\FlashPlayer");

if (RK != null)
{
    // It's there 
}
else
{
    // It's not there 
}
```

In registry If I search for flash player with version 10.2.161.23, the location

> "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Macromedia"

is having 2 folders:

1. FlashPlayer and
2. FlashPlayerActiveX.

But, my above code is not working.

Kindly let me know how to check if a particular version of flash player is installed in a system or not **USING C#.NET**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adobe's old (pre 10) IE Flash detection code used to test in VBScript if it could instantiate object ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.<major version>. If it's just the major version you want to test, you can check for those keys under HKCR, e.g. `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.10`.

[SWFObject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/source/browse/trunk/swfobject/src/swfobject.js) instantiates the version-less object name, ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash, and queries its `$version` property. To do this in C#:

```
// Look up flash object type from registry
var type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
if (type == null)
{
  // No flash
  return;
}

// Create a flash object to query
// (should probably try/catch around CreateInstance)
var flashObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
var versionString = flashObject.GetType()
                      .InvokeMember("GetVariable", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                    null, flashObject, new object[] {"$version"})
                    as string;
// e.g. "WIN 10,2,152,26"

// Clean up allocated COM Object
Marshal.ReleaseComObject(flashObject);
```

Comment: But I need in C#.NET, not in javascript. How to achieve this in C#.NET.

Comment: Sorry if my question sounds silly. I am new to this. What is "BindingFlags.InvokeMethod"  in this.Can u kindly explain other parameters. Thanks in advance

Comment: They're parameters to [Type.InvokeMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/66btctbe.aspx) used in .NET Reflection. What's going on: we need to invoke the method `GetVariable("$version")` for a COM object that we don't have a pre-built COM interop component for. (It might actually be an IDispatch method on the COM object anyway.) The easiest way to do this is using reflection: I'm calling GetVariable; it's a method not a property (the BindingFlags); use default reflection binder (null); invoke this method on the flashObject; pass a single parameter "$version", the variable we want.

Comment: Just spotted I hadn't cast the result to a string: edited in.

Comment: Thank you. :)  Your answer solved my problem. But have 1 query. my system has 2 versions of flash. 10.1.102.64 (32 bit version) and 10.2.161.23 (64 bit version). But its detecting only 10.2.161.23. Why not the other 32 bit one.

Comment: In this case we're getting the Flash version that's available for your .NET process to use. It will only return the one, depending on whether the .NET code is running as 64-bit or 32-bit.

Comment: But its detecting the version 10.2.161.23 only IFF other version 10.1.102.64 is installed. If my system has only 10.2.161.23 then its returning null. PLz help me with this. What is the fix?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. This is probably a 64-bit vs 32-bit issue and I don't have a lot of experience with those.

Comment: Is it possible to detect if it's a Beta version?

Comment: @Velcro I don't know, sorry. I don't think I've seen a beta Flash version for some time. I'd guess if there was a flag it'd be in the registry somewhere or perhaps on the COM interface too.