# How to check if the 64 bit version of flash player 10.2.161.23 is installed in the system or not IN C#?

Tags: c#, flash, 64-bit

I had earlier asked the question in stackoverflow in the followin link-

> [How to check if a particular version of flash player is installed or not in C#.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039636/how-to-check-if-a-particular-version-of-flash-player-is-installed-or-not-in-c)

```
Type type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash");
object flashObject = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    object versionString = flashObject.GetType().InvokeMember("GetVariable", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,null, flashObject, new object[] {"$version"});
```

But my code is able to detect the 64 bit version 10.2.161.23, only when, the other 32 bit version 10.1.102.64 is installed on the system.

> But when I uninstall the other version
>   10.1.102.64, from the system, my code is not detecting the 64 bit version
>   10.2.161.23 and the value of "type" varable is "null".

I dont know why that the 64 bit version needs a 32 bit version flash to be present for detecting the presence of 64 bit version, using the above code.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution is this function taken time ago from another site:

```
    public static bool IsApplictionInstalled(string p_name)
    {
        string displayName;
        RegistryKey key;

        // search in: CurrentUser
        key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        if (key != null) foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // search in: LocalMachine_32
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        if (key != null) foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // search in: LocalMachine_64
        key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall");
        if (key != null) foreach (String keyName in key.GetSubKeyNames())
        {
            RegistryKey subkey = key.OpenSubKey(keyName);
            displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;
            if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // NOT FOUND
        return false;
    }
```

You can try to play with it to perform your search, like subkeys and changing this:

```
if (p_name.Equals(displayName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
```

To this:

```
if (displayName.Contains(p_name) == true) //"Flash Player" is your case... (untested)
```

Source: http://mdb-blog.blogspot.com/2010/09/c-check-if-programapplication-is.html

Comment: May I know what does the string "DisplayName" in the statement displayName = subkey.GetValue("DisplayName") as string;  signify.. PLz let me know

Comment: Is a subkey of the registry, you can see it all by open RegEdit and go to one of the voices as shown in the code...
The field you need to check is also "DisplayVersion", you can pass it as search criteria for searching software name and his version...