# Is there an Adobe equivalent to the Java deployment.properties file?

Tags: c#, java, flash, adobe-reader

Just as the title states, is there an Adobe equivalent to the Java deployment.properties file?

I am writing a c# application to test installations of application in our network. The top three on my boss's list are java, flash, and reader. I need to be able to find out what versions of each application are installed on a machine for the reports im going to generate (force the user to update/etc).

I know i can check version number and confirm the ability of IE to access my JRE by checking "\Sun\Java\Deployment\deployment.properties". What file would I check to confirm the same for adobe reader and flash?

Thanks in advance for any help given or links provided to more info.

edit: I need to do this from the browser.

Comment: Possible duplicate for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039636/how-to-check-if-a-particular-version-of-flash-player-is-installed-or-not-in-c

Comment: @codeghost i dont think it's a dup. They one you reference is for a registry key for flash player. I am looking for a file that contains that information. I wish I could use a registry key, but it is outside the scope of my project. I will only have file access, not registry access. My question stands as specific to files. Thanks though!

Comment: I was referring to the answer which instantiates an object in C# and interrogates it for the version, thought that would work for you.

Comment: @codeghost thank you. That does not currently meet my requirements and scope.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a very clean solution, but since the only "official" way seems to be to check it from the Windows registries perhaps this will help:

We know that the flash files are located are in the (windows directory)\system32\Macromed\Flash (or SysWow64\Macromed\Flash on 64 bit systems).

Each time a flash updates it keeps the track of the progress in the log files. Depending on the flash version you will either have a) install.log (very old versions of flash) or b) FlashInstall.log

**a)** If you browse through the file you see various entires and one type goes like this:`WriteRegStr: "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer" "FlashPlayerVersion"="10.0.45.2"`.

Now you can just go through that file bottom-top and match the `"FlashPlayerVersion"=` string to get the most recent version.

However, this is for a really old versions of flash and the install.log file never got deleted from this directory, so make sure you check for the **FlashInstall.log** too!

**b)** Use a similar approach, except the new install logs don't keep the "WriteRegStr" information. Now you can instead look for the dll file name itself, for example my last update created an install log `0009 [I] 00000014 C:\WINDOWS\system32\Macromed\Flash\NPSWF32_11_5_502_146.dll`, meaning my flash version is 11.5.502.146

**another options** are to

- check the plugin core files creation date and compare with the versions release dates (quite unreliable in case someone somehow manages to install an older version)
- check the actual property of the NPSWF[..version..].dll file. You can see all the complete and precise version details in the "Version" tab.[image: the properties] however, I don't know how to access the rightclick->properties from inside a script, so you'll have to find out by yourself if you decide to go for this option
- ask the unicorns

Comment: Thank you for your response. My apologies for the delay in my response but i set the email incorrectly and didnt receive the update that you responded this weekend. I am going to try and use your solution today. After some testing i will respond with my results and go from there. Thank you!

Comment: I just gave this method a shot and on about 10 machines i have flash, reader, and java installed for testing purposes and none of them have values in the registry "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Macromedia\FlashPlayer". Am I missing something here or is this value manually set?

Comment: try HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. also, if you decided to go for my option 1.a - you probably want to go for the option 1.b, that log file is for the newer versions of flash. also2: these solutions don't directly deal with the registry, because you say you don't have access to it... if you have an access to the registry, use the registry of course

Comment: would i be able to use registry if i had to take another route? say via the browser? At this point, I am looking for any solution that can get me a couple of version numbers so we can auto push updates to those machines when the user checks in.

Comment: i am not sure what are you asking, i don't really know your workplace configuration. accessing registry via browser should be strictly forbidden because of security issues. but if you are looking for a way to access it via unsecure IE here is some guide which makes use of some active scripts http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156602.aspx. if you need help with registry access, perhaps you should make another question

Comment: I was mostly trying to expand on your suggestion from above. I am not sure this method is going to work within the restrictions i have. Basically I am adjusting the homepage of the intranet to check what versions of reader,flash,and java JRE people are running. I have successfully tested against java by using the file i mentioned in my post but i am unable to repeat success with anything adobe.